# Java jersey connect to Amazon DynamoDB issue

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, jersey, amazon-dynamodb

I am using jersey and try to connect to amazon dynamodb. But it throw exception. This was what i did.

- create dynamic web app
- add jersey lib to Web App Libraries
- add aws sdk for java
- write some endpoint code

This is my code

```
@Path("/auth")
public class SLAuth {
@POST
@Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
public Response sayPlainTextHello(@Context HttpHeaders headers) throws Exception {
    AmazonDynamoDBClient dynamoDB  = null;
    AWSCredentials credentials = null;
    try {
        credentials = new ProfileCredentialsProvider("default").getCredentials();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        throw new AmazonClientException(
                "Cannot load the credentials from the credential profiles file. " +
                "Please make sure that your credentials file is at the correct " +
                "location (/Users/macos/.aws/credentials), and is in valid format.",
                e);
    }
    dynamoDB = new AmazonDynamoDBClient(credentials);
    Region usWest2 = Region.getRegion(Regions.US_WEST_2);
    dynamoDB.setRegion(usWest2);
    return Response.status(200).entity("{\"status\":\"OK\"}").build();
}
}
```

When i post a message, it throw exception:

```
Apr 10, 2016 12:10:01 AM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve invoke
SEVERE: Servlet.service() for servlet [Jersey REST Service] in context with path [/sl] threw exception [org.glassfish.jersey.server.ContainerException: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/amazonaws/auth/profile/ProfileCredentialsProvider] with root cause
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.amazonaws.auth.profile.ProfileCredentialsProvider
at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.loadClass(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:1305)
at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.loadClass(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:1139)
at sl.giangchau.SLAuth.sayPlainTextHello(SLAuth.java:31)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
```

Could you give me some advice?

**---- SOLVED ----**

So silly, I did not add AWS SDK to Web App Libraries.

Comment: It seems that you are not deploying the jar containing ProfileCredentialsProvider.class to your server.

Comment: My advice is to read the error message. Really read what it is saying and attempt to understand it instead of just giving up and asking for help.

Comment: Have you added AWS SDK to your Web App Libraries?

Comment: @MarkB i had read the error message and thought that i missed something. i am new to server programming and spent 1 day for this issue. :D Anyway, thanks you for your advice :3

Comment: @RubioRic Thank for your suggest. It solved my problem.